# How can I add many users with known passwords

Tags: rocket.chat

I'm setting up a rocket chat server in an air gapped testbed where I'll have thousands of automated users talking to each other to generate network traffic.  I had seen the user import via CSV documented [here](https://rocket.chat/docs/administrator-guides/import/csv/).  That lets me create my users, but not with pre-assigned passwords.  Looking in `programs/server/packages/rocketchat_importer-csv.js` I see that it is setting the password to a formulaic string including the current date.

That's as good as a random password for my needs.

Is there a way to, say, include another column in the CSV where I can assign the password for each user?

I installed it via snaps on Ubuntu 16.04.4 if that affects anything.

Comment: It is a bad habit to use CSV or JSON for storing passwords because they can be seen publicly. Use binarized version or a database instead.

Comment: Thanks, but as noted this is for fake users on an air gapped network to generate test data.  The passwords will then be stored in plain text config files for the bots to know how to login later as well.  In general I agree with you, but as a specific piece of test equipment I'm being, shall we say, rather free with security concerns (some times that's the specific point of a test run even, so becomes a hard requirement for me, not just a convenience).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm too trying to import MD5 hashed passwords to Rocket Chat

Comment: @Zolbayar I just posted the script I  ended up using, but I'm not sure it'll help with already-hased passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I wrote a python script to do the job making a web request for each line of the CSV.  Here's what I came up with:

```py
import csv
import json
import requests

def main(csv_path, admin_user, admin_pass, base_url):
    """
    Read the given CSV of the format:
        loginname, email, real name, password

    and create all the users described in it in the Rocket.Chat server
    available at `base_url`
    """
    login_json = json.dumps({'username': admin_user, 'password': admin_pass})
    response = requests.post(base_url + '/api/v1/login', data=login_json)
    data = response.json()['data']
    token = data['authToken']
    userid = data['userId']
    headers = {
        'X-Auth-Token': token,
        'X-User-Id': userid,
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
    }

    with open(csv_path) as raw:
        reader = csv.reader(raw)
        for user in reader:
            request = {
                'username': user[0],
                'email': user[1],
                'name': user[2],
                'password': user[3],
            }
        ret = requests.post(base_url + '/api/v1/users.create',
            data=json.dumps(request), headers=headers)
```